# PHP new strings update in DB with unshift?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, insert-update

I have a problem to adding more strings in my database.
**The idea is:** SELECT information, then added array together, after these UPDATE to database.
These are in one code, but UPDATE not working with summed arrays only separately.
With echo I see the array_unshift is working well, the data is good, but not updating.
Need I change something on the server? Maybe version?
(I don't get mysqli_error!)

```
//CHECKBOX KIOLVASÁSA DB-BŐL!
$sql = ("SELECT id, checkbox FROM osszesito WHERE id = '$id'");
//$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    //EREDETI SOR LISTÁZÁSA
    $original_array = array( $row["checkbox"] ); 

    $x ="";
    echo 'Eredeti sor: '; 
    foreach ($original_array as $x)  
    { 
      echo "$x "."<br><br>"; 
    }     

    //EREDETI SOR KIEGÉSZÍTÉSE AZ ÚJ ADATTAL      
    array_unshift($original_array, $chb);  

    $last ="";
    echo "Új sor: "."<br>"; 
    foreach ($original_array as $last)  
    { 
      echo $last."<br>"; 
    }   


    //ÚJ SOR FRISSÍTÉSE A DB-BEN!
    //$sqla = "UPDATE osszesito SET checkbox = '$chb' WHERE id = '$id' ";

    $sqla = "UPDATE osszesito SET checkbox = '$last' WHERE id = '$id' ";


    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqla)) {

      echo "ÚJ SOR ELMENTVE!";
      //header("Location: /megrendelesek/index.php"); 

    } else {
      echo "Hiba a beírás során: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }


  } 

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//LEZÁRÁS

} else {
  echo "Jelenleg nincs megrendelés az adatbázisban!";
}


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I have literally no idea what this code is supposed to do. What are the loops for?

Comment: I have uncountable checkboxes. New orders with new checkboxs, with unique IDs.
I try to save these IDs. 
1. I read out the IDs from DB. ($row["checkbox"])
2. First loop show me what is or are in the array
3. unshift help me to add new ID of the start.
4. Second loop show what is in the new array.
5. $sqla update new datas to DB.

Is it easier way to add new string in DB without deleting what is in cell?
Just adding to beginning or to end?

Comment: I have found the solution. After the first loop just I need to add together with very simply mod: $last = ($x.$chb); Then this is working in update and I see it in DB. You have open my mind, because I checked why I need 2 loops. Thanks.